# Azure Encrypted Disks

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault

I had an Azure VM that got delocated and i could not redeploy it.

I can find the old OS and DATA drive files but i cant get then opened in other vms due to not having the encryption vaults anymore.

Something went wrong with my subscription and i had to clean it out.

And maybe in that cleaning session i removed the keyvault containing the encryption keys for them.

Is there any other way to get back to the BEK file that can unlock the drives?

Tried to redeploy the old vm which failed due to errors with the keyvault.

tried attaching them to a new vm that sees them as bitlocker encrypted.

NVT

Access to BEK file or access to the drive itself so i can get some data of it.

Comment: My gut says yer outta luck.. but you should really be asking Microsoft about this.

Comment: You can open a support ticket with MSFT to request they un-delete the keyvault associated with the VMs. It could be possible depending how long ago you deleted and the resources actually removed. Without that there is nothing much else that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If the Keyvault is deleted (and completely gone) you will not be able to get information to unlock disk.  The first step is to get information on the keyvault used to encrypt drive. Assuming it's managed disk you can use powershell to get the keyvault information;

```
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -DiskName <OsDiskname>
$disk.EncryptionSettingsCollection.EncryptionSettings[0].DiskEncryptionKey.SecretUrl
$disk.EncryptionSettingsCollection.EncryptionSettings[0].KeyEncryptionKey.KeyUrl
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwecV.png]

Once you have keyvault information you can check if keyvault and secret exist, if they do you are in luck.

Answer (score 0):

Was the VM joined to Active Directory?  If it was and the device still exists then the recovery key may be there.

For Azure AD, go to Active Directory -> Devices -> Search & Select -> Bitlocker Recovery Keys

Windows Server AD:

1. dsa.mmc -> View -> Advanced Features
2. Right click domain -> Search
3. Change object type to computer and type name -> Search
4. Right click the computer object if found -> Bitlocker Recovery